# Generate a signed url using a generation number using gsutil

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have the following versions of a file in my GCS bucket:

```
gsutil ls -a gs://xyz-dev

gs://xyz-dev/test.txt#1589869975626596
gs://xyz-dev/test.txt#1589869994788057
gs://xyz-dev/test.txt#1589870007230315
```

When trying to create a signed url using:

```
gsutil signurl -r us-east1 -d 1d ~/creds.json gs://xyz-dev/test.txt#1589869975626596
```

I get a link generated for the latest version of the file. This only happens using gsutil. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its seems you are not doing anything wrong, it looks like an issue in the gsutil tool. 
I could reproduce the issue and I reported it to the Cloud SDK product team in  [this Public Issue Tracker thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/157117278) where you will be able to track further updates regarding this issue.